# How do I programmatically query the state of the timeline "record" button?

Tags: python, scripting

I have a frame handler that should set keyframes if the record button is set. How do I check whether it's enabled via Python?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you place the mouse cursor above the record button, you will see:

```
bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].tool_settings.use_keyframe_insert_auto
```

[image]